# Is there anyway to clear my Flash Projector history?

Tags: windows-10, privacy, history, flash-player, private-browsing

Ever since Flash died, I have been using the flash projector provided by the Adobe people. The flash projector is very excellent, except for the fact that it makes it obvious what you have been using it for. It shows up to the last 9 files you have accessed using the projector. I tried deleting the flash player cache, but that just deleted all the data for my games and did nothing for my history. Please help, thank you.

Forgot to add this, I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The article
[How to delete Windows Flash Player 10.1 Projector opened file history?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/flash-player/how-to-delete-windows-flash-player-10-1-projector-opened-file-history/td-p/3232609)
describes using registry editing to remove file history:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Macromedia\Flash Player`
- The previous history is present under this key as values named `RecentMovie#`
- Delete the history items to clear up the list.

A gap in the history numbering may cause all following entries to not be displayed.
If that happens for you, then deleting `RecentMovie1` may be enough.

(Be very carefull when doing registry updates.)

[image]

Comment: This is the [Registry Editor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10-deab38e6-91d6-e0aa-4b7c-8878d9e07b11), but this is an advanced utility that shouldn't be used without some understanding of how Windows works.